# Python writing and reading a txt file

Tags: python

```
def replace():
    import tkinter.filedialog
    drawfilename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    list1= int(open(drawfilename,'w'))
    del list1[-3:]

    input_list = input("Enter three numbers separated by commas: ")
    list2 = input_list.split(',')
    list2 = [int(x.strip())for x in list2]


    list1[0:0] = list2
    list1.write(list1)
    list1.close()

    import tkinter.filedialog
    drawfilename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    list1= open(drawfilename,'r')
    line = list1.readlines()
    list1.close()
```

I want to open a `.txt` file containing `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`,  remove the last three values then ask a user to input three numbers and add them to the beginning of the list ( example input `12,13,14` gives `12,13,14, 1,2,3,4,5,6`). Then I want to overwrite the original list with this new list. When a user opens the routine again, I want list1 to be the new list1.
With the help of stackflow I get the new list1, but am having difficulty opening and rewriting to the text file. The error that global list1 has not been declared stops the routine from progressing.

Comment: You should read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).  Your code has a lot of problems.  For starters `list1 = int(open(drawfilename,'w'))` tries to convert a file to an integer, which doesn't make sense.  Even if that worked, `del list1[-3:]` tries to treat `list1` as a list, when you previously assigned an integer value to that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really confused on how to use a file.

First of all, why are you doing `int(open(filename, "w"))`?
To open a file for writing just use:

```
outfile = open(filename, "w")
```

Then files does not support item assignment, so doing `fileobject[key]` does not make sense. Also note that opening a file with `"w"` *deletes* the previous contents! So if you want to modify the contents of a file you should use `"r+"` instead of `"w"`.
You then have to read the file and parse its contents. In your case is probably better to first read the contents and then create a new file to write the new contents.

To write a list of numbers to a file do:

```
outfile.write(','.join(str(number) for number in list2))
```

`str(number)` "converts" an integer into its string representation. `','.join(iterable)` joins the elements in *iterable* using a comma as separator and `outfile.write(string)` writes *string* to the file.

Also, put the import outside the function(at the beginning of the file possibly) and you do not need to repeat it everytime you use the module.

A complete code could be:

```
import tkinter.filedialog

def replace():
    drawfilename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename() 
    # read the contents of the file
    with open(drawfilename, "r") as infile:
        numbers = [int(number) for number in infile.read().split(',')]
        del numbers[-3:]
    # with automatically closes the file after del numbers[-3:]

    input_list = input("Enter three numbers separated by commas: ")
    # you do not have to strip the spaces. int already ignores them
    new_numbers = [int(num) for num in input_list.split(',')]
    numbers = new_numbers + numbers
    #drawfilename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()  if you want to reask the path
    # delete the old file and write the new content
    with open(drawfilename, "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(','.join(str(number) for number in numbers))
```

Update:
If you want to deal with more than one sequence you can do this:

```
import tkinter.filedialog

def replace():
    drawfilename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename() 
    with open(drawfilename, "r") as infile:
        sequences = infile.read().split(None, 2)[:-1]
        # split(None, 2) splits on any whitespace and splits at most 2 times
        # which means that it returns a list of 3 elements:
        # the two sequences and the remaining line not splitted.
        # sequences = infile.read().split() if you want to "parse" all the line

    input_sequences = []
    for sequence in sequences:
        numbers = [int(number) for number in sequence.split(',')]
        del numbers[-3:]

        input_list = input("Enter three numbers separated by commas: ")
        input_sequences.append([int(num) for num in input_list.split(',')])

    #drawfilename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()  if you want to reask the path
    with open(drawfilename, "w") as outfile:
        out_sequences = []
        for sequence, in_sequence in zip(sequences, input_sequences):
            out_sequences.append(','.join(str(num) for num in (in_sequence + sequence)))
        outfile.write(' '.join(out_sequences))
```

This should work with any number of sequences. Note that if you have an extra space somewhere you'll get wrong results. If possible I'd put these sequences on different lines.

Comment: You are write. I am completely new to this and am totally confused. THank you for your help. Much appreciated

Comment: MAy I add a question to the original one. How would the script look if the txt file contained two lists separated by spaces and one wanted to write to both lists eg 1,2,3,4,5    8,9,10,11? Ask for two sets of numbers to be entered. THe soltion above works perfectly, thank you very much

Comment: @user1478335 You mean you have a file with a single line of the form `1,2,3,...,11 SPACE 3,4,5,6,..,12` and you want to ask the user two sequences and update the file? Should the input from the user be treated as before, deleting the last three items in the sequence and adding the numbers the user provides at the beginning?

Comment: Exactly as before and as you describe. THank you so much for your help. I was completely lost with the logic

Comment: When using the update, I get an error:sequences = infile.read.split()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'splitI have a txt file with two sequences of comma-separated numbers separated by a tab ( also did not work with a single space separating the two lists). Obviously I am doing something wrong. Please indulge me with more help!

Comment: @user1478335 Sorry, it was a typo. It should be `infile.read().split()` with the parentheses. Fixed it now.

Comment: New error now:File "C:\Python33\documents\replace_multiple.py", line 10, in <listcomp>
    numbers = [int(number) for number in sequence.split(',')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang2057{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0'Sorry to waste your time like this. I have absolutely no idea how to trouble-shoot this. Am reading the Python tutorial as suggested though, so hopefully...

Comment: @user1478335 That's because your file also contains some other data, which you did not tell me about. I'll modify it so that it only takes the first two "pieces" separated by spaces.
On a side note, in the interactive python interpreter you can do `help(str.split)` to see what a method does(works for function and classes too).